# How to upgrade Laravel from 5.7 to 5.8

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8

I have been googling and reading on this for several days. 
I am unable to update my Laravel project from 5.7 to 5.8, due to dependencies. When I update the dependency package version values in composer.json and try to perform a laravel update, it ignores my updates, and actually reverts them back to the original values.

Composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.0",
    "chriskonnertz/open-graph": "^1.0",
    "cmgmyr/messenger": "^2.16",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.6",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
    "egeloen/http-adapter": "^1.0",
    "eilander/gateway": "^5.6",
    "exodusanto/administrator": " 5.7.*",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.8",
    "geocoder-php/bing-maps-provider": "^4.0",
    "geocoder-php/chain-provider": "^4.0",
    "geocoder-php/google-maps-provider": "^4.2",
    "geoip2/geoip2": "^2.9",
    "hemp/presenter": "^1.0",
    "hieu-le/active": "^3.5",
    "htmlmin/htmlmin": "^5.8",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.7",
    "league/period": "4.1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "morrislaptop/laravel-queue-clear": "^1.1",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "php-http/message": "^1.7",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.5",
    "pragmarx/firewall": "^2.2",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "prettus/l5-repository": "^2.6",
    "prettus/laravel-validation": "^1.1",
    "ryanwinchester/hubspot-php": "~1.0",
    "sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "^3.5",
    "santigarcor/laratrust": "^5.0",
    "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.2",
    "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^4.0",
    "torann/geoip": "^1.0",
    "venturecraft/revisionable": "^1.28",
    "watson/sitemap": "^2.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^8.9"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

Steps I take:

1) Edit my composer.json file, changing: "laravel/framework": "5.7.*"

to: "laravel/framework": "5.8.*"

2) Run composer update

Output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package egeloen/http-adapter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-http/httplug instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run ".\vendor\bin\upgrade-carbon" to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: anhskohbo/no-captcha
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: chriskonnertz/open-graph
Discovered Package: cmgmyr/messenger
Discovered Package: cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
Discovered Package: exodusanto/administrator
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: hemp/presenter
Discovered Package: hieu-le/active
Discovered Package: htmlmin/htmlmin
Discovered Package: intervention/image
Discovered Package: laravel/nexmo-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravel/passport
Discovered Package: laravel/slack-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravel/socialite
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: morrislaptop/laravel-queue-clear
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: pragmarx/firewall
Discovered Package: prettus/l5-repository
Discovered Package: sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk
Discovered Package: santigarcor/laratrust
Discovered Package: spatie/laravel-newsletter
Discovered Package: toin0u/geocoder-laravel
Discovered Package: torann/geoip
Discovered Package: watson/sitemap
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Result:

composer.json file has been reset to show : "laravel/framework": "5.7.*"

Things I've tried: 
1) Deleting the composer.lock file prior to attempting this. 
2) Performing a php artisan cache:clear prior to my updates.

There has to be someone out there who has experienced these issues that can help me out.

Comment: Are you following the official upgrade guide? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#upgrade-5.8.0

Comment: Yes, I am following the official upgrade guide. It IS supposed to be simple, and I don't know why it's doing this. I've upgraded from  4 - 5.4, 5.4 - 5.7, and now, all of a sudden, what I've done in the past isn't working.

Comment: I should probably restate this in a slightly different way: I actually tried to avoid the composer update reverting back to the original value by: 1) deleting the composer.lock file, 2) performing a php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Could you add the exact steps you're attempting and maybe include the relevant parts of your `composer.json` to your question please? Then we can see if we can reproduce what you're experiencing.

Comment: @delena-malan, I've updates my question, please review when you have a chance.

Comment: Are you sure that you are working in the same directories? I've never seen that a `composer.json` is changed in any way when calling `composer update`. You could try running it with `--no-scripts` such that no other external actions are triggered

Comment: Lol. Turns out the IDE (Eclipse Neon) was never updating my composer.json file even though it indicated I was. I edited it from the command line, and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Just follow the [Official Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#upgrade-5.8.0):

1. Update your `composer.json` `laravel/framework` to `5.8.*`
2. Run `composer update`. There's no need to deleting `composer.lock
3. Check the upgrade guide above for changes that might affect uour application. This version have almost no breaking changes.

Comment: Yes, you would think that's all there is to it, and I've done 2 much larger upgrades in the past, but for whatever reason, it's not working for me. What you outlined is what I did initially. I began doing those other things because It didn't work.

Comment: I've update my post, please review when you have a chance

Comment: Definitely the right answer. Also, as the creator, I'm going to mention the Shift which [automates Laravel upgrades](https://laravelshift.com/upgrade-laravel-5.7-to-laravel-5.8).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the IDE (Eclipse Neon) was never updating my composer.json file even though it indicated I was. I edited it from the command line, and it worked.

Answer (score -3):

My personal experiences in this sort of situations has learned me to create a brand new project with new version of Laravel and then add my personal changes (i.e. controllers, models, migrations, views, configurations, etc.). Of course using unit tests will help you a lot to successfully upgrade your project to the next level.

BTW. [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade) may help you to upgrade safely but again, I highly recommend to use a brand new installation instead of dealing with a mess of changes.

Comment: It's just a minor version upgrade. Just a few changes.

Comment: I know. You can follow the link but consider "High Impact" changes in mind such as cache duration (in 5.7 you set it in minutes but in 5.8 you should calculate it in seconds). Of course only features you've used are important. Again, we are talking about Laravel. My personal experience tells me it's always better to have a clean install.

Comment: Of couse. I do it when jumping multiple versions, it's faster in that situation.

Comment: I might have to, I just was hoping not to. I believe that's what I did in my upgrade from 4 to 5.4.

Comment: I've update my post, please review when you have a chance